# How to combine `css-modules` with normal `sass`, preferably in `webpack`

Tags: sass, webpack, css-modules

**TLDR:** How to combine `css-modules` with normal `sass`, preferably in `webpack`.

### The Setup:

I am working on the styling build process for an e-commerce website. The site's styles are currently done in **sass** along with the **js** through a **gulp** **browserify** build process.

I have recently added a single page app that is built using **react** with **webpack** and **babel**. Inside of that application I am taking advantage of [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) provided by **webpack** to scope the class names to each **react** component.

### The problem:

I would like to incorporate the styles from the webpack `css-modules` build in with the main styling bundle for the site. To do this, I was considering building a webpack configuration to build the styles for the whole site. The problem I have is how to get the styles which are currently built by the single page webpack configuration and inject just the style chunk into a global webpack configuration that handles styles for the whole site. I should mention that I would like to keep the two configurations as separate as possible

### The Questions:

- Is there a proper way of having decoupled webpack builds where one is still able to use chunks from the other?
- If so, how do I do it so that the `css-module` setup stays in the single page configuration, and the `extract-text-webpack` part along with a boring sass build goes into a global configuarion?
- If not, how should I go about having one section of sass go through the `css-modules` workflow, and still combine it with the bundle from the rest of the site.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
based on @Alexandr Subbotin's answer, I have updated my webpack to look something like the code below. I did have to change names and paths because of the code belongs to my employer, so there may be slight errors.

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const JSDIR = './build/js/';
const STYLES = './build/css/bundle.css';

module.exports = {
    entry : {
        'styles'   : './src/styles.scss',
        'app'      : './src/index.js',
        // a javascript file that includes the root of the single page app.
        'single-page' : './src/single-page/styles-entry.js', 
    },
    output : {
        path     : JSDIR,
        filename : '[name].js', // normally compiles my 
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader : 'babel-loader',
            query : {
                presets: [
                    'react','es2015','stage-0',
                ]
            },
          },
          {
            test : /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style?sourceMap', 'css?-url&sourceMap!sass?sourceMap'),
            exclude : /\/single-page\//,
          },
          {
            test : /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
              'style?sourceMap',
              'css?-url&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=SinglePage__[name]__[local]!sass?sourceMap'
            ),
            include : /\/single-page\//,
          }
        ]
    },
    plugins : [
      new ExtractTextPlugin(STYLES, {
          allChunks : true,
      }),
    ],
    resolve : {
        alias: {
            "eventEmitter/EventEmitter": "wolfy87-eventemitter",
      },
      extensions: ['', '.js','.jsx'],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question you want to apply css-modules only to one part of your application and leave simple sass building process in other parts.

To do this you can use `exclude` and `include` options in loaders. I.e. if you have your single page application inside `single-page` directory your webpack config can be:

```
module: {
  entry: {
    // it is your global sass styles
    application_css: './css/application.scss',
    // it is main file of your SPA bundle. Somewhere inside you will use require('./styles.scss') that should be processed by css-modules
    spa_index: './single-page/index.js'
  },
  loaders: [
    ...,
    {
      // This loader will build all your sass that are not in `single-page` directory
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass'),
      exclude: /\/single-page\//
    },
    {
      // This loader will handle all your css module in `single-page` directory
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: 'style!css?modules!sass',
      include: /\/single-page\//
    },
  ],
  ...
}
```

So, in this case all css from `single-page/` will use css modules, and the rest won't.

#### EDIT:

If you take a look in [API](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin#api) section of ExtractTextPlugin documentation you find

> The ExtractTextPlugin generates an output file per entry, so you must use [name], [id] or [contenthash] when using multiple entries.

In your example you have have two chunks with css (`styles` and `single-page`), but only one output `./build/css/bundle.css`. If you change your output to `./build/css/[name].css` your will have two css files: `styles.css`  with your global css and `single-page.css` with SPA styles.

Comment: This definitely gets me a little further, but I need to output both chunks through `ExtractTextPlugin.extract`.  When I set it up that way, webpack claims both chunks are in the output css, but only the second chunk is making it in there.

Comment: output with both chunks: http://screencast.com/t/Rn9tpQ36A. Output is smaller than with just one chunk: http://screencast.com/t/Vt2cbfrwv

Comment: I should mention that I did try to use `allChunks : true`, and when that didn't work I tried using two `ExtractTextPlugin` instances pointing at the same filename. both resulted in the same results as above.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your webpack config? As I think it should work if you use `ExtractTextPlugin.extract` for global styles and another for single page with `include/exclude` options in loaders sections and `new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css', { allChunks: true })` in plugins section

Comment: webpack config added.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the whole point of this exercise was to get everything in one file, since I already have two builds capable of producing two separate files.

Comment: Another way of doing it, with greater flexibility than `include`/`exclude` is applying a similar trick to `test`, in order to match mutually exclusive files. Non modules: `test: /^((?!\.module).)+?\.scss$/`, modules: `test: /\.module.scss$/`.

Comment: I haven't been using that naming convention, but I was able to do it with an ugly regex for the directory in `test`. In my case the exclude/include makes for a much cleaner config.